# redhat 5.4 python-ldap run error (python2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I install python-ldap-2.4.13 to redhat5.4, and run then get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/openerp-server", line 5, in <module>
    openerp.cli.main()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130923_231151-py2.7.egg/openerp/cli/__init__.py", line 51, in main
    __import__(m)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130923_231151-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/module.py", line 133, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130923_231151-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/auth_ldap/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import users_ldap

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130923_231151-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/auth_ldap/users_ldap.py", line 21, in <module>
    import ldap

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_ldap-2.4.13-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import _ldap

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_ldap-2.4.13-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/_ldap.so: undefined symbol: ldap_create_assertion_control_value
```

How can I fix it? pls help, thanks very much!

Comment: Your OpenLDAP and the python-ldap library versions are not compatible. Remove the python-ldap library you have installed, and install a lower version; try 2.3.13

Comment: for what it's worth, as of today the only versions shown that are on pypi are 2.4.x [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap/), BUT you can get to it directly [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap/2.3.13)

Answer (score 1):

This is the KEY-Point,it work for me!

> Your OpenLDAP and the python-ldap library versions are not compatible. Remove the python-ldap library you have installed, and install a lower version; try 2.3.13 –  Burhan Khalid Oct 11 '13 at 12:40

And you can get the old releases from [CVS](http://python-ldap.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/python-ldap/python-ldap/?pathrev=PYLDAP_REL_2_2_1)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You will have to install python-ldap by modifying setup.cfg.

For me I had to use: /usr/lib64/openldap24 and /usr/include/openldap24